# 404 rewrite or redirect nginx path

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Im having problems with redirect on nginx

I have this original URL:

```
https://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/logo.png
```

And i'm using the Cloudflare Image, i can use this to load by Cloudflare Image:

```
https://www.example.com/cdn-cgi/image/onerror=redirect/media/wysiwyg/logo3.png
```

But i need this dynamic, like:

Everything in this folder: "media/wysiwyg/" will redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,onerror=redirect/media/wysiwyg/logo.png
```

logo.png would be dynamic, BUT MUST BE AN IMAGE (JPEG, GIF, PNG).

I tried this, but without success:

```
location ~ ^/media/wysiwyg/(.*)$ {
    rewrite    ^/media/wysiwyg/(.*)$ /cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,onerror=redirect/media/wysiwyg/$1 break;
}
```

I need, if i access this:

```
https://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/logo.png
```

I need redirect to this (without change url):

```
https://www.example.com/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,onerror=redirect/media/wysiwyg/logo.png
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `break` to `last`.

Because the new URL will need to be processed by a different `location`, you need to have nginx restart processing for the new rewritten URL, which is only done when you use `last` in the `rewrite` rule.

See [the docs](https://nginx.org/r/rewrite) for the complete explanation of how `rewrite` works.